# Is there a good site for drug reviews?

Tags: medications, prescription

I have have it difficult to research the drugs I am prescribed. I was wondering if there are any websites that are good sources for reviews concerning drugs. I have no idea how to find a trustworthy source, fake reviews are well known online.

For example, I recently found this site while trying to research my asthma medication:
https://treato.com/BREO+ELLIPTA,Asthma/?a=s

I have no idea if I can trust this website at all.

Comment: Hello, questions asking for recommendations are generally not a good fit for Stack Exchange. Please considering weighing in on [this Meta discussion](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/384/165) if you have thoughts about how these could be effectively dealt with on this site. Thanks!

Comment: @Susan, though this can involve opinion, I do not think it has to be considered _bad_. The NYT is considered a reliable source, for example, so my question is really aiming to look for a reliable source of drug reviews. Asking for reliable sources of news might return the BBC, NYT, and NPR. Some may disagree, and no source is perfect, but it is legitimate. It isn't a fake site, it is something that generally warrants trust. Do you know of any such sites for drug reviews? I doubt there are any and it would be hard to find a reliable site like that, unless it was by an NGO or something.

Comment: Hi zagadka314, at the moment it looks like the top answer on that meta question says `Recommendations asking for resources where you learn about medical or health related topics should be on-topic.`, so I am re-opening. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't see any reason treato shouldn't be trusted, but they don't actually offer much. All they are is a search engine that goes out and plucks posts from other sites that match whatever it is you search for. If you try to read the full text of one of the posts, it actually just takes you to the web site where it was found, so you have to view all the ads on the other sites. I found it largely useless and annoying.

Comment: @CareyGregory I didn't think it was very useful, but that rating of this drug surprised me. The side effects it listed also did.

Comment: can i ask what kind of review are you looking for i mean professional or experimental people review , webmd.com have both of them but if u like physician drug reference or pharmacist guides i can give u a list i have no reference for my answer so i didn't answer unless u want